# Enable core dumps in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, arch-linux, dump

I would like to enable core dumps in my Apache web server.
Since I have PHP 5.5 and OPcache my Mediawiki site crashes with the following error:

```
child pid ... exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

So I would like to get more information through the core dump.

I created a directory: `/tmp/apache-coredump` owned by `http:http` (my apache user and group) and with the 777 rights.
I added to the `httpd.conf` file:

```
CoreDumpDirectory   "/tmp/apache-coredump"
```

But, now (with the CoreDumpDirectory instruction) my Apache server crashes on start-up:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd

Job for httpd.service failed. 
See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

The journal give me the following info

```
apachectl[4149]: CoreDumpDirectory /tmp/apache-coredump does not exist
```

I checked, the directory exist 0_°

**Edit:**
I changed the `CoreDumpDirectory` instruction in the `httpd.conf` file and it allows me to start my web server

```
CoreDumpDirectory /tmp
```

---

Without the CoreDumpDirectory instruction, there is no core dump generated in the ServerRoot (`/etc/httpd`) directory.
I'm on Archlinux 3.10.6-2 64-bits with Apache/2.2.25 Prefork

Comment: I can't be sure based on your description. But is it possible that you run apache in a root jail? that would be a reason why it can't find that directory.

Comment: I don't think my web site is in a root jail (but I'm sure of nothing today). How to be sure I'm not and what to do if I am?  I tested `/tmp/apache-coredump` as a file and it failed, but I tested `CoreDumpDirectory /tmp` and it allowed me to start Apache but without core dump.

Comment: You can be sure if you start your apache without the coredump parameter, so it starts successfully. then you check for the pid of one of the apache processes, then you execute `ls -lha /proc/<pid>/root`. the root entry of the <pid> folders in /proc is always pointing to the root for that process, so if the process is running in a jail root, this should point to somewhere else than `/`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The `ls -lha /proc/<pid>/root` command returns `/`. So my web server doesn't run in a root jail :) `CoreDumpDirectory /home/<user>/folder` also works but doesn't allow me to generate the core dump file.

Comment: @Dennis Kaarsemaker, SELinux is not installed on my Archlinux system

Comment: I had the same issue, and after trying various things I also ended up setting `CoreDumpDirectory ` to just `/tmp`. But in any case, I guess the subdirectory would be deleted on a reboot, causing apache not to start. Perhaps it rejects subdirectories of `/tmp` for that reason... but it seems a bit far-fetched.

Answer (score 3):

Core dumps are generally disabled by default since they tend to waste disk space, you need to switch them on for your apache session.

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
[...]
$ ulimit -c unlimited
$ systemctl restart httpd
```

Also, do you have SELinux enabled? Output of `ls -alZ /tmp/apache-coredump`

Comment: `ls -alZ /tmp/apache-coredump` -> `drwxrwxrwx  2 http http ?  40 19 août  21:40 .`  `drwxrwxrwt 18 root root ? 520 19 août  21:40 ..`  But as `/tmp/apache-coredump` failed with the CoreDumpDirectory instruction I use `/home/<user>/apache-coredump` -> `drwxrwxrwx  2 http    http    4096 19 août  18:01 .`

Comment: Thanks for the ulimit tip, I passed from 0 to unlimited but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone.

Note that if you have `PrivateTmp=true` set in your `/usr/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service` (or whatever it's called on your system), meaning Apache actually looks for `/tmp` inside something like `/tmp/systemd-private-c27fc5b152d546159d675e170641529b-apache2.service-IcEt0m/`, Apache won't be able to write to that dir and you won't get cores dumped at all (due to the `systemd` tmp directory having 700 root-only perms).

The solution is to either set `PrivateTmp=false` or modify the permission of the systemd tmp directory after the server starts.

I wasted hours on this to only just now finally realize what the problem was.